# Route 53 provide the geolocation of a user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

So we have a multi tenancy application, when a user request comes in. I know in Route 53 we can route to a different server. But is it possible to determine the location ie Europe or Asia. ie like add to a header?

Ideally I'd like to pass this information forward to our application. I know that Route 53 provides the Geolocation routing policy. But can it pass this information forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that route 53 provides the Geolocation routing policy. But can
> it pass this information forward?

The answer is NO.

How would a DNS server pass that information to a client? DNS servers translate domain names to IP addresses (for the most part). There are no DNS fields where the geolocation details can be returned. When you say header, you probably mean HTTP header. HTTP is at a different layer in the OSI stack. Each type of application would have a different concept of encoding geolocation.

Comment: HI, that makes sense. Is there anyway i could get the locale perhaps from the request in the application?

Comment: @user1555190 - implement geolocation in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You could have your application listening on multiple IP addresses. With different geolocation records for each IP address, you could determine which geolocation record was used by which IP address the user connects to.

That said, there are probably better ways to determine the user's location. Since Route53 is determining location by IP address (I assume), you can do the same in your application's code.